# Functional equation $f(2x)=2(f(x))^2 -1$

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

Given that $f(x)$ is differentiable, $$f(2x)=2(f(x))^2 -1$$

I can assume that $f(x)=cos(ax)$, but I can’t think of a way to prove that it is the only solution. In fact, I am not sure that $f(x)=cos(ax)$ is the only solution. All i know is that $f(0) = -{1 \over 2}$ or $1$.

Comment: Note the constant functions $f(x)=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x)=1$ are also solutions (with the latter one actually being part of your solution where $a=0$).

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(2x)%3D2(f(x))%5E2-1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Adifferentiable&p=3), there's part (a) of the AoPS thread [Functional equation:](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1658281p10515489) (although that only requires that $f(x)$ be continuous), and the quite similar [Find all functions $f$ satisfying $f(2x)=2f(x)^2 -1$](/q/3524515) (with this having somewhat different conditions on $f(x)$ than yours).